# Cell standby and Phone idle

Tags: battery

On the battery use screen, what are the differences between Cell standby and Phone idle items?

[image: Battery usage statistics: Cell standby and phone idle]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think "phone idle" just means general power use from the phone being on (listening for user activation, waiting for scheduled app actions, basic memory and CPU "being on" stuff etc.) whereas "cell standby" is about keeping the phone active on the cell network (brief signals back and forth with cell towers alerting them of your presence, listening for calls or SMS).

Comment: Sounds about right.

Comment: what is the "Android system" item about then?

Comment: Android system refers to the operating system itself: app management, opening and closing apps, boot time, etc.