# How to monitor signal strength?

Tags: samsung-nexus-s, network-signal

I own a Samsung Nexus S 4G on Sprint, and I am having terrible but intermittent problems with my signal quality on my phone. I have reasonably high certainty that this is a hardware issue (my wife has the same phone on the same plan and her phone usually works where mine does not), but due to the fact that the problem is intermittent I have not been able to duplicate it in the Sprint store.

What I am looking for is a way (perhaps an app) that will periodically poll and record the signal strength on my phone, as well as recording when my phone fails to connect on a call (during the periods when my phone is acting up this will sometimes occur 10-15 times in a row). Are there any apps that provide this functionality, or would have anyone have any advice on developing this app on my own (I am a decent programmer, but I have never developed an Android app).

Answer (score 3):

There are a some apps available which would answer your question. The probably best ones include...

**[NoSignalAlert](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smartandroidapps.missedcall)**, which not only alerts you when you lost the signal, but also provides a log<sup>[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAcNH.jpg)</sup> of those events, and lets you even browse those "dead zones" on a map and display the collected log information along<sup>[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCn0J.jpg)</sup>

[image: NoSignalAlert Log] [image: NoSignalAlert Map]

**[OpenSignalMaps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.staircase3.opensignal)**, offering similar features, and giving you the ability to show nearby cells<sup>[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUGmL.jpg)</sup> (so if your signal is low, and you want to have a conversation, you can move in the right direction<sup>[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LokcB.jpg)</sup> for a stronger signal)

[image: OpenSignalMaps Cells Near] [image: OpenSignalMaps Cell Compass]

If you are primarily interested in mapping signal quality, **[Antennas](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.technolatry.antennas)** might be worth a look as well<sup>[5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8AGb.jpg)</sup>. It can export collected data to KML, so you can display it in Google Maps / Google Earth on your computer as well.

[image: Antennas]

Then there also is already mentioned **[RF Signal Tracker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hotrod.utility.rfsignaltrackereclair)**, again rather interesting for mapping<sup>[6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pVX9.jpg)</sup>, which additionally tracks Wifi signal

[image: RF Signal Tracker] [image: RF Signal Tracker]

Last but not least: **[G-NetTrack](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gyokovsolutions.gnettrack)** is also good for mapping<sup>[8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6nvU.jpg)</sup> of daily routes and the like.

[image: G-NetTrack]

---

What might be of even more interest to you is how to automatically react on a weak signal in order to save some juice. If so, I recommend you taking a look at the question [What is *Cell standby* and how can I keep it from eating my battery?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29447/what-is-cell-standby-and-how-can-i-keep-it-from-eating-my-battery/29449) (and of course its answer).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you [Better Battery Stats](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.asksven.betterbatterystats), it's what you are looking for.

Comment: While being a very good app to determine where your juice went to, it does not log the times when your signal was low. And I don't see the OP asking for battery consumption to monitor, but rather for the cell signal.

Answer (score 0):

Check [RF Signal Tracker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hotrod.utility.rfsignaltrackereclair)

Also [Open Signal Maps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.staircase3.opensignal)