# How to make android prefer mobile data when wifi signal is very weak

Tags: wi-fi, 4.1-jelly-bean, data-connection, network-signal

When I leave home or the office there is a ring around it where I simply have no connection at all. This is because the WLAN network from my router at home or the one at the office is detected, but the signal is so weak that no useful data flow can occur.

Is there a way in which I can make android use the mobile data network when the WLAN signal strength is below a certain strength so that there isn't this annoying "dead ring of no connectivity"?

Googling this problem or searching the app store keeps giving me solutions for the exact opposite.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From Android 5 onwards, there's a setting in the *Developer options* called *Aggressive WiFi to mobile handover*.

Enabling this setting makes your phone switch to mobile connection when the WiFi signal is too weak.

You can also take a look at [a tutorial with screenshots](https://mikalikes.men/force-android-to-switch-to-mobile-internet-on-weak-wifi/).

Comment: Unfortunately this option has since been removed

Answer (score 6):

You can do so by having your WiFi switched off when its signal gets weak. There are several apps available on the Playstore which can watch the WiFi signal, one of them being [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) (which is what I use). Here you can define a minimum level and tell *Tasker*: If WiFi signal falls below this, switch WiFi off. Of course you can make it even more detailed, and letting it check every X minutes whether signal quality has improved. It might be a little tricky to set up first (especially when one is not used to *Tasker*) -- but once it works, and you figure out what else can be done with that app, you don't want to miss it. An example how this could look like can be found in [What is *Cell standby* and how can I keep it from eating my battery?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29447/16575) -- a little different topic, but a similar idea behind it.

You might also take a look at similar apps. Though *Tasker* is not free (you can get a 7-day trial on their website), it's worth every cent -- but might be hard for beginners. There are other automation apps around, as e.g. [Llama](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kebab.Llama), which might also able to do a similar job.

Comment: Thanks I will consider purchasing that app (which I was already doing anyway, but I was hoping for onX to become facebook independent).

Comment: If you either considered buying *Tasker*, that's the best way. It's a real powerful tool; I could answer almost every second question with "Tasker" ;)

Comment: Is it possible to have tasker to turn wifi back on when there is a strong signal again?

Comment: @MeyerDenney should be similar to [this one](/a/29449/16575). Of course requires to enable WiFi in intervals to check (how else should it know).

Answer (score 3):

In Android 4.4, there is an explicit option for this:

Settings -> WiFi -> Advanced Wi-Fi -> Avoid poor connections

In Android 5, this option appears to have been removed. There is an [Android bug/feature](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=81843) with many complaints on this.

Comment: [Auto (or Smart) Network Switch](http://www.samsung.com/au/support/skp/faq/1045889) now exists.

Answer (score 1):

[BestSignal](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eightythirty.bestsignal&hl=en) seems like the perfect solution. It offers both default configurations and also advanced configurations.

Comment: Just bought this and it seems to fix the issue!

Answer (score 0):

I just installed [BESTSIGNAL](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eightythirty.bestsignal) on my HTC ONE M7 from the developer of the [same name](https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=BestSignal). It's the paid version but only AUD1.99 and it works well, simple yet highly functional GUI. However it was not compatible on my Google Nexus 7 (2012) nor my ASUS Transformer TF700T so be sure to check your device compatibility.