# Any way to reduce the frequency of searching for a signal

Tags: battery, network-signal

My fiancee just got my old SGS2 when I got my new N5.  The problem that she's having is that there is no cell reception at her work.  And because of this, her phone is constantly searching for a signal all day long, and by the time she leaves work and gets into an area of reception the phone is dead.

I've told her to just turn it off or put it in airplane mode, but she usually forgets.  I know I could set something up with tasker, but that sounds like a pain, and I don't really want to pay for on app she'd hardly use.

phone is SGH T989.  I believe she's on 4.2.something.

Really what I'd like to be able to do is just have the phone not try so hard to find a signal when there isn't one available.  I looked and didn't really see a system setting for this.  Is there maybe an app that someone can recommend that would work?

Comment: You most certainly and for sure want to check [What is *Cell standby* and how can I keep it from eating my battery?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/29447/16575). Some solutions there. Oh, including *Tasker* (I no longer can do without), but also alternatives.

Comment: @Izzy I'd mark your comment as the best answer if I could.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar problems and used Llama, then expanded my use of it to cover other events. It is similar to Tasker, and sufficient to my needs, while still a free app. Most automation can be triggered by entering/leaving cell tower range that is recognized as "Home". It has options to turn on Airplane mode automatically when the phone leaves a cell reception range, and take it out of Airplane mode when it re-enters.

BTW - I'm just an enthusiastic user - not the developer.

Comment: That's interesting.  How does it know it's re-entered cell reception if it's in Airplane mode?

Comment: @matthew - It can be set to ping periodically until it finds the cell tower(s) identified as "Home", pinging can be stopped or delayed, resuming after a certain time, say 16:00.