# How to drop out of airplane/flight mode periodically to check messages

Tags: battery-life, airplane-mode

I normally keep my phone in Flight Mode (called "Airplane Mode" under 2.2) in order to save battery power.  When I have some time to check messages, I turn off Flight Mode, re-enabling the cellular transceiver.  Is there a way I can set up my phone to momentarily drop out of Flight Mode periodically, say every 10 minutes, preferably without using a non-free app?

I don't really need it to be in Flight Mode per se, just to disable power-draining devices, especially the cellular transceiver.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple automation tools which most likely can do this for you. Some of them, especially in connection with your real concern, are listed in my answer to [What is *Cell standby* and how can I keep it from eating my battery?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/29447/16575).

Aside from that, and you might wish to check helpers like [JuiceDefender](http://www.appbrain.com/app/juicedefender-battery-saver/com.latedroid.juicedefender), [Easy Battery Saver](http://www.appbrain.com/app/Easy-Battery-Saver/com.easy.battery.saver), and [GO Battery Saver & Widget](http://www.appbrain.com/app/GO-Battery-Saver-Widget/com.gau.go.launcherex.gowidget.gopowermaster). Amongs others, they do exactly what you asked for: toggling airplane mode or rather the data part of it, to enable apps to sync only in defined time frames.