# Moto X Battery Question

Tags: battery, battery-life, 4.4-kitkat, motorola, moto-x

I'm new to android and the Moto X.  (iPhone 4s previously.  don't judge.)  I purchased my Moto X a couple days ago (2/15/14) and overall I'm very happy.  The battery life has me concerned though.  Last night before I went to bed I checked the battery and when I woke up I checked it again.  I slept for about 6.5 hour and my phone died went from 63% to 47%.  16% for being idle for 6.5 hours seems like a lot to me.  Previous phones would maybe lose a percent.  Any thoughts or suggestions?

[image]
[image]

Not for sure what 'Android OS' includes it is pretty vague.  It would be nice to see exactly what is causing the drain of 55%.

Overall it says 17h 39m 3s on battery at the time of this post.  I unplugged it around 2pm yesterday afternoon.  Very light use of the evening and like I said 63% went to bed.

** Update **
Over the past hour or so I've been searching the web looking at screenshot similar to those above.  100% of them have 'Screen' as their highest percentage and 'Android OS' at a much lower percentage.  I must have something turned on that is causing Android to use more CPU time?

I'm running on AT&T with a KitKat 4.4 build.  Still waiting for the 4.4.2 push.

Comment: Is it sleeping at all? Android OS is generally the OS related activities, syncing, checking for system updates, et cetera.

Comment: The screen is black the entire night.  It has active display and will light up when I move it and show my clock and any notifications.  But to answer your question the screen definitely stays black.

Comment: Right, but is it going into standby? If you look at the battery use screen, you should see a line graph followed by the top battery (ab)users. If you tap the graph, it should expand and show you signal quality, how often the device slept, the screen was on and how often the GPS device was being queried. 

I see this on my SGS4, but I think this same UI should be on the MotoX.

It could be something is not letting your device sleep. I will say 17 hours is pretty good for an android device. I can barely make 8. But I use it a lot during my commute so there's that.

Comment: @WhiskeyTangoFoxtrot I uploaded some images.  It isn't the time the battery has been off the charger it is the fact it lost 16% in 6.5 hours sleeping that concerns me.

Comment: @KyleRogers did any of the answers help solving the issue (you didn't yet accept any of them, so this might not be the case), or is still anything missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue gets pretty clear by the second screenshot, which I will repeat here:

[image: Battery Usage]
<sup>Battery usage (click image for larger variant)</sup>

Please pay attention to its lower half, just below the graph, and let me point out some details:

- **Mobile network signal:** This bar has no black, which means the radio was on all the time. Further, the colors indicate a relatively weak signal (see [my answer here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/29449/16575) for details), which most likely caused the device to permanently watch out for a "stronger signal source", powering up the radio for that, and consuming energy for this task.
- **Wi-Fi:** again, a continuous bar, so WiFi was turned on the whole time, consuming energy again.
- Interim result at this place: With all sync on (as it is by default), the device would also permanently synchronize your data (in intervals, of course) – contacts, calendars, etc.pp. – which again consumes battery.
- **Awake:** This bar clearly shows your device was not in "permanent standby". You always find "blue spots" on it, even during your sleep period (which most likely is, where the **Screen on** graph is black but there are blue spots on the "Awake" graph – i.e. most of the "last third")
- **Charging:** Continuous black, so no charger was connected. Guess where the juice had to come from then :)

**Conclusion:** Pretty normal behaviour, though I cannot speak *precisely* how much battery-use would be normal (that depends on too many factors unknown to me, as e.g. apps installed, sync intervals, "consumption specifications" of device components, and so on). If you feel it should last longer, consider switching to airplane mode at night (or turning at least WiFi off). There are even tools available which would automate this – some of them e.g. mentioned with my above linked answer.

Comment: As always, brilliant post Izzy

Answer (score 3):

This actually sounds pretty normal to me.  If this screenshot was taken shortly after you woke up then it would make sense for the OS to have used more battery, since the screen would have been off for a long while.  I've owned several Android phones, having worked for Verizon Wireless before becoming a developer, and I've never had an Android phone that I would trust to leave unplugged at night.  Without fail, whenever I've done this (always by accident) whatever phone I was using lost a lot of charge by the time I woke up.

Having said that, I would check and see how frequently your phone is checking for new emails, as well as checking how often any other apps (like news apps, Facebook, whatever) are refreshing in the background.  Checking  your sync settings on any apps you are using, or even ones you may not be actively using, could make a big difference in battery life.