# Unexplicable battery draining on Galaxy Nexus

Tags: custom-roms, samsung-galaxy-nexus, battery-life, stock-android

Okay, so first some details:

- Samsung Galaxy Nexus (GSM version)
- Stock rom (rooted)
- Brand new stock battery (1750mah)

I started suffering from unexplainable battery draining a few months ago. And with that I mean draining from fully charged to empty in less than 10 hours with almost no usage at all.

I must add that I frequently flashed custom roms on there, particularly unofficial 4.4 roms for maguro (galaxy nexus). As a last resort, I installed the original and last release of JB on it again, for me 4.3 yakju.

Since that also did not fix the problem I bought a new stock battery on ebay. I thought that obviously the battery must be broken, since it would also drain battery even when powered off. Except the fact that the battery drains less slowly, the battery is also draining spectacularly (it now drains in 12-13 hours approximately)

As a final note: I am now running stock 4.3, with virtually no apps installed. Syncing is off, no wifi, no 3G no nothing. Even with my old battery, it would last a day with moderate usage.

[image: My battery history details]

**So my question is whether you guys have any ideas or leads of what might have happened? Did I fuck up my phone by wrongly flashing it? If so, is there something that can still save my phone?**

Comment: Have you tried looking in **Battery** in the **Settings** app to see what is using it?

Comment: Mostly `Phone idle` and `Mobile standby` are at top. For instance now it has been discharging since 2h57m, it has 81% left with 4 mins of screen time. Phone idle is on 39%, screen on 37% and mobile standby on 17%. (further below are Android system and Android OS, each with 3-4%)

Comment: Sounds like: [What is *Cell standby* and how can I keep it from eating my battery?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/29447/16575) Please check the colors for your mobile network in that very same graph. I assume many red and gray-green here, and only little "clear green". How's coverage in your area? Did you notice a "drop" with that as well?

Comment: I attached a screenshot. I cannot say I notice a drop related with signal,neither does it seem to be too bad.I'll check your link out anyway, thanks :)

Comment: Try installing [BetterBatteryStats](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1179809) which will give you more detailed info as to what is eating the battery.

Comment: I did, and there is nothing unusual there. Most of it is in deep sleep, no abnormal wakes...