# Notification on Connecting to Network Carrier

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, htc-one

Simple question. I work in a basement office and my network signal is very patchy at best. Is there a way to get a notification (buzz preferably) when it finds a signal? I have an HTC One running Kit-Kat (4.4.3). My favourite search engine hasn't given me any joy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there's nothing built-in to be used. And for apps, I only know the opposite: buzzing you when the alert is *lost* (see: [Bad Signal Alert](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_cellsignal#group_404)).

However, you could use [tasker](/questions/tagged/tasker) to create your own customized solution. *Tasker* can monitor signal strength, and you can setup a profile to utilize that. I cannot give you the matching profile currently, but you might wish to take a look at [What is *Cell standby* and how can I keep it from eating my battery?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/29447/16575) In my answer there I've introduced a longer configuration involving the necessary tasks, so you might be able to adapt them to your needs. In fact, the *SigReturn* task already does what you asked for: Whenever the signal is restored, it issues a vibrating notification.

<sup>Being older than 2 years already, it might need some polish, though :)</sup>

Comment: Keep in mind, signal strength is not always 100% accurate. What shows, or is reported, may not be the current signal strength. It's the strength that it had the last time it checked the signal strength.

Comment: @RyanConrad sure. That's why one always should have a "delay" in. If I remember correctly, I used something like "if signal strength falls below X, wait y seconds and check again. If it's still below X, act." Still not "really safe", but at least "safer" than acting immediately on a "fluke" ;)

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't calling your answer incorrect in any way, it is actually a really good idea and could be reliable enough.

Comment: @RyanConrad I didn't take it that way, no worries. I rather considered it a good and justified hint – and thanks for that! It's quite a while ago I last experimented with that profile (conditions improved, better signal now, so no need anymore) – so I really wasn't sure whether that was covered appropriately ;)