# Can I customize the signal strength threshold for disconnecting WiFi?

Tags: applications, wi-fi

Android's default threshold is too high, resulting in the system sometimes not cutting off WiFi even though the signal is already too weak to access the Internet. So I would like to set the threshold manually.

Comment: So you want to let your device switch earlier to a different Wifi or should it switch to cellular data? For the latter I think Android has an option and for switching Wifi there are new Wifi extensions which handle seamless roaming among Wifi hotspots that belong to the same WiFi. Unfortunately these extensions have to be supported in hardware by phone and access points.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. We have a possible duplicate of a similar issue: [How to set signal strength threshold for switching WiFi on and off?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/122992/44325). Please take a look and let us know the result. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Robert, this function is usually performed by Wifi Access Points that support "Active Handover" function.  That's what I have at home, but it doesn't work elsewhere.

I have been using [Wifi Switcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.softmediacts.wifiswitch) App

> Automatically switch to a better WiFi network when current signal is weak
>
> Ensure you stay connected to the most powerful Wi-Fi network available. The best WiFi roaming app available.
>
> By default, Android devices will not switch to a different Wi-Fi network as long as the current network connection is available, although the signal level is very weak and makes the network unusable.

There are many others that might work, But I haven't tried them.

- [Smart Wifi Switch](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.suphi.smartwifiswitch) which is free
- [SmartWiFiSelector](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tartar.strongestwifi) which is paid

I am not associated with any of them.