# how to stop Lollipop Cell Standby Drain

Tags: 5.1-lollipop

I updated to lollipop on my Moto X phone and I am now seeing a large percentage of my battery being used by Cell Standby. How do I stop this?

Comment: See the award winning answer to understand the problem: [What is \*Cell standby\* and how can I keep it from eating my battery?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/29447)

Answer (score 3):

I have dealt with this bug a lot. (Moto x gen 1) The good news is that Google has assigned someone to fix it, however right now the best way to fix this is to force close apps when you are done using them.

What is happening is when an app requests cellular data, your phone's data radio turns on. In most cases the radio immedietly turns off when it is done, but there is a lollipop bug that keeps the radio on until the app that requested it is force stopped.

The force stop can be done manually through the running apps list in settings, but there is another app called Greenify that will do this for you automatically. No, you won't need the paid version. Just let the app have accessibility access and it will force close apps for you on request.

If you want proof, here is what my cellular battery usage is when I forget to use Greenify all day.

[image]
<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

And when I use it vigorously

[image]

(I am in no way affiliated with Greenify or its development team)

Comment: Hi thanks for the tip. But is there any way to know which app causes this? I can't just kill everything that may or may not use cellular internet.. Like the android wear app service :S

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no other way. I essentially learned to accept the problem. I plan on flashing my Moto x 2013 to cyanogenmod 14 to fix this and protect myself from all of these new android vulnerabilities that keep popping up once it becomes stable.

Answer (score 0):

Turn airplane mode on. Airplane mode will disable cell standby while active.If you need wifi, you can turn it back on without cell standby turning on.

Answer (score 0):

Only solution is to downgrade to 4.4.4...
I've faced this bug on my XT1058, and was not able to solve it for good (I could disable the bug for a while, but eventually reappeared).
After downgrading to KitKat, phone works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:

Short answer:
  Settings (gear) -> System Update -> Update Motorola software

Medium answer:
  Using Moto X (2013 a.k.a. Moto X1 )
  “System version” is now “222.21.19...."
  Also helps to use MOTO instead of GOOGLE assistant to save battery

Long answer:
  I finally let “Motorola Update Service” upgrade from Android 4.4 to 5.1
  Also let “download manager” upgraded apps.
  BUT it reported “Cell standby” using over 20% of battery.
  This is after disabling or stopping every App possible and letting it sit on the desk.

But all the other upgrades have "nag screens" or are "automated".
  "Update Motorola software" is a manual process.
  After the update... the "screen" is back to being my top "Battery" user,
  everything else is 1%.