# Unexpected battery drain when idle (Samasung Galaxy Note 5)

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, battery-life, samsung-galaxy-note

I am having issues with battery drain and not sure what to do, my note will lose about 30% battery overnight(about 7-8 hours) and last night it lost about 50%.

At first it said that google app used a lot of battery so I disabled the recommended things online (it's location and such), now it isn't draining as much.

Also my location doesn't use GPS, at night I always have maximum reception and yet I lose a lot of battery to cell reception, also the other 2 you can see in the picture.

Hope someone can help, and thank you!

[image: screenshot of battery drain statistics]

Comment: Arguing by the screenshot: Please tap the graph for additional details. "Cell Standby" having the top position suggests you had very bad reception, so the device might have used that power to find a better signal. See: [What is *Cell standby* and how can I keep it from eating my battery?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/29447/16575)

Comment: Thing is I have full reception all the time, sounds strange that it would be the issue :\

Comment: Have you checked the graph I indicated? Cell bar always dark green, no exception?

Comment: does your device getting hot beside this battery drain ?

Comment: Izzy I am note sure where I can see that, didn't really understand and no, that device is quite cool when idle

Answer (score 1):

Check your data usage. In my case, I found the Cloud service had used about 0.8GB of data over night (1.32GB over 2 days), the phone could not recharge fast enough, and it was hot. The amount of data in cloud storage is only 138MB, so I have no idea what that all of that data usage consists. If you have this issue, disable the Cloud app. Other things to check are location services settings, WiFi scanning, notifications. After the Marshmallow 6.0 update, all notifications get turned on by default.