# Battery drains on airplane mode when there is no cellular reception

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, samsung, battery, airplane-mode

I always turn on the airplane mode on my phone running Android 5.0.2 before I go to bed. It's working great as there is at most 10% drop in battery percentage(usually around 6%). I have noticed a problem with my phone and I think it shouldn't happen(this is my first phone). When there is no cellular reception, my phone will try hard to find one and the battery starts draining(which is normal), but it still tries to search for reception even I enable airplane mode, which is the odd part. It is okay since my phone is able to receive reception after a few minutes.

Few weeks ago, my phone completely died overnight with airplane mode enabled. I am sure I have closed all running apps, and I didn't have GPS and Bluetooth on. I tried to search online but I found no clue.

[image]
[image]

This happened again today. I could feel that my phone was warmer than usual and I knew something must have went wrong.

[image]
[image]

Is there a way to prevent my phone from searching for cellular reception on airplane mode? Or is my phone faulty? I already have `Always allow scanning - Let Google Location Service and other applications scan for Wi-Fi networks, even when Wi-Fi is off` disabled long time ago but I don't think it has anything to do with my problem.

Comment: Is your phone rooted?

Comment: @beeshyams Nope

Comment: *...tries to search for reception even I enable airplane mode...* - curious as to how you tracked this  If it is because of *cell standby*, this [question](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/29447/131553) may help

Comment: Easy. First the battery percentage goes down a lot faster on idle and my phone warms up. Also, it says "No service" on the lockscreen on airplane mode, which goes away after there is cell reception. The answer to fix the problem in that post is to enable airplane mode, which doesn't work in my case :\

Comment: Try dialing ` *#*#4636#*#*` and from phone info turn off the radio to see if the symptoms are reproduced

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me. My phone is still getting cell reception.

Comment: In which case, it appears to be OS issue ( to me ) and you may need to factory reset or flash stock OS

Comment: Factory reset will be my last option. I'll wait and see if the others have the similar issue. Thanks for your help :)